# i want to get name from the webapi . but its throwing error showing. cannot implicitly convert type model to ihttpactionresult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i have created one class "student". added 3 elements in the list. i want to get one name . but its giving compile time error.

```
 using testWEBAPI.Models;

namespace testWEBAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MyapiController : ApiController
    {
        public List<student> s = new List<student>()
        {
        new student{name="krishna",city="hyderbad"},
        new student{name="priya",city="mumbai"},
        new student{name="sandeep",city="jamshedpur"}
        };

        public IHttpActionResult getnames()
        {
            return Ok(s.ElementAt(0).name);
        }
    }




}
```

*routing*

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

desired out put - krishna,hyderabad

Comment: `s.ElementAt(0)` would return a `student` object, not a `IHttpActionResult`

Comment: i need to get just a string in web api for that how can i do ?

Comment: If you are using WebApi 2, use the `ResponseType` attribute to indicate what type you are returning.  If you are not using WebApi 2 then I strongly suggest that you do.  The Routing is much nicer and simpler for a start.

Comment: sorry i just forgot to add the api in the url before controller. i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
return Ok(s.ElementAt(0));
```

This is happening because the method is expecting you to return IHttpActionResult.

Alternatively you can change the method to expect a Student object to be returned.

Comment: i have to do  changes in routing.i have updated my question. routing is ther

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
public student getnames()
{
    return s[0];
}
```

This will get you JSON of your `student` object.

If you need a string just transform your `student` object to a string as you require and use the `string` for method return type.

Comment: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

http://localhost:18024/myapi/getnames

Comment: maybe your student is not public, not sure why it cannot find this method. Or most likely you did not configure your WebApi routing at all? Check a simple string with return hello world to be sure.

Comment: student class is public only. i have not configured webapi routing at all

Comment: Why do you even ask this question then? Obviously if you have not configured routing it won't know anything about your `myapi/` url part. This is completely different question from the compiler error you had.

Comment: actually earlier it was showing comping error . which i think its solved but i did nt get output, so i asked for the solution. sorry

Comment: If you need solution for a new problem, you should rather ask a new question. It was not obvious that you referred to a new problem in the comment (I did not know you have not set up the webapi routing). Sorry, I was a bit too straightforward as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, I think

```
namespace testWEBAPI.Controllers
{
    public class MyapiController : ApiController
    {
        public List<student> s = new List<student>()
        {
        new student{name="krishna",city="hyderbad"},
        new student{name="priya",city="mumbai"},
        new student{name="sandeep",city="jamshedpur"}
        };

        public HttpResponseMessage getnames()
        {
            string name = list.Select(x=>x.name).ElementAt(0);
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, name);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

In case if you are returning the list of names use this

```
 public HttpResponseMessage getnames()
 {
      var name = list.Select(x=>x.name);
      HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, name);
      return response;
  }
```